# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Tags: javascript, web-audio

Скрипт не воспроизводит аудио. Почему?

```js
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
  var exdate = new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
  var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
    x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
    x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    if (x == c_name) {
      return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var played = false;
var tillPlayed = getCookie('timePlayed');

function update() {
  if (!played) {
    if (tillPlayed) {
      song.currentTime = tillPlayed;
      song.play();
      played = true;
    } else {
      song.play();
      played = true;
    }
  } else {
    setCookie('timePlayed', song.currentTime);
  }
}
setInterval(update(), 0.0001);
```

```html
<audio src="http://bestweb.kl.com.ua/media/75519871_456239030.mp3" preload="none" autoplay="autoplay" loop="true"></audio>
```

Comment: я так понимаю народу не нравится, что код приведен не полностью. вставьте html-снипет.

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка появляется из-за того, что воспроизведение пытаетесь запустить по ходу загрузки страницы, т. е., без взаимодействия с пользователем. Чтобы такого не было, нужно запускать по нажатию на кнопку, или включить в тег аудио атрибут **controls**, который показывает изображение плеера и даёт возможность на нём нажать на кнопку воспроизведения.
Кроме этого для реализации идеи, чтобы после обновления страницы песня начинала звучать с того же самого момента, что её оборвали, не обязательно запускать плеер и задавать currentTime внутри setInterval(). К тому же, период 0.0001 составляет одну десятую часть микросекунды, (даже не милисекунды) это просто фантастический период, для этой цели достаточно одной десятой секунды. Учитывая это всё, я бы сделал так:

```html
<audio src="http://bestweb.kl.com.ua/media/75519871_456239030.mp3" preload="none" autoplay="autoplay"  loop="true"></audio>
<button onclick="playsound()"> play </button>
<script>
var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
function playsound(){
 var tillPlayed = localStorage.getItem('timePlayed');
 if(tillPlayed)song.currentTime = tillPlayed;
 song.play();
 myinterval = setInterval(function(){localStorage.setItem('timePlayed', song.currentTime)}, 100);
}
song.onended = song.onpaused = function(){clearInterval(myinterval)};
</script>
```

Правда, этот пример не на куках, а на localStorage, что-то так мне больше нравится, но можно поменять обратно на куки.